# in sqlite3, `select * from myTable where 1=0` - will it skip table scanning?

Tags: sqlite

Given the query:

- `select * from myTable where 1=0`,

if i do:

- `explain query plan <above_query>`

it says:

- `> scan table myTable`

...is this true though? Will it actually do a table-scan (i.e. scan every rows in the table)? or will it actually skip table-scan and return an empty-result-set immediately knowing that the given `where clause` can never evaluate to `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite prepares a plan with a table scan, but it actually skips the whole scan.
If you execute

```
explain select * from myTable where 1=0;
```

you wil get this compiled plan:

```
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     9     0     NULL           0   Start at 9
1     Ne             2     8     1     NULL           80  if r[1]!=r[2] goto 8
2     OpenRead       0     2     0     2              0   root=2 iDb=0; t
3     Rewind         0     8     0     NULL           0   NULL
4       Column         0     0     3     NULL           0   r[3]= cursor 0 column 0
5       Column         0     1     4     NULL           0   r[4]= cursor 0 column 1
6       ResultRow      3     2     0     NULL           0   output=r[3..4]
7     Next           0     4     0     NULL           1   NULL
8     Halt           0     0     0     NULL           0   NULL
9     Transaction    0     0     1     0              1   usesStmtJournal=0
10    Integer        1     1     0     NULL           0   r[1]=1
11    Integer        0     2     0     NULL           0   r[2]=0
12    Goto           0     1     0     NULL           0   NULL
```

It will start by jumping at line 9, setting up the transaction and loading 0 and 1 in two registers, then it will jump back to line 1.
It will then compare the two registers and, finding that the two values are different, it will jump to line 8 and stop, without even opening the table.

Sqlite isn't optimized to know that 1=0 can never evaluate to true, but it does realize that the expression doesn't depend on any column of the table, so it evaluates it only once for the whole SELECT, and not for every row.